# Holdout object but keep its reflections and shadows?

Tags: rendering, shaders, compositing-nodes

I’m adding 3D-rendered jewelry to a photograph. I want my blockout of the hand not to appear in the final render but still to cast shadows and reflections on the jewelry and obscure the part of the jewelry that's behind it.

If I use Holdout, the chain doesn’t get reflections from the hand:
[image: With holdout, the chain is darker.]

In GIF form:
[image: Switching back and forth between holdout and no holdout.]

These are the hand's object properties:

[image: Holdout is checked within Visibility.]

If I omit the hand from the render altogether, the hand doesn’t cast shadows or block the jewelry behind it.

How can I achieve a render with the following?

- Hand blocks jewelry behind it
- Hand casts shadows and reflections
- Hand itself doesn’t appear

Thank you!

Comment: Hi :). Just curious- are you using holdout shader, holdout collection or holdout object?

Comment: I'd make two renders - first one with full reflections, second with holdout area, and then combine the alpha channel in compositor :))

Comment: @JachymMichal I selected Holdout in the object properties (edited my post to explain that). Thank you for the idea about two renders! I'll try to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use cryptomattes in the *Compositor*. To do that, you first have to go to *View Layer Properties* > *Passes* > *Cryptomatte* and check *Object*.

[image: view layer passes]

Now I render a scene. Like yours it has a transparent background, one object (the red sphere) is obstructing the other from the camera and is visible in reflections on the second object (the blue sphere).

[image: original image]

If you now place a *Cryptomatte* node - not _Cryptomatte (Legacy)! - between the *Render Layer* and the *Viewer* and/or *Composite* node, at first everything disappears. That's because no matte object is chosen yet.

[image: empty image]

Switch from the *Image* output to the *Pick* output of the *Cryptomatte* node. All available objects are now visible in different colors. You can now click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button next to the *Matte ID* field. Then you'll get an eyedropper tool with which you can click on the object you want to pick as being visible - in this case the blue sphere.

[image: pick object]

Going back to the image output you will now see only the blue sphere. The red sphere is still visible in the reflection on the blue sphere.

[image: blue sphere]

As with other masking methods in Blender, you might see a slight red border remaining in the new image. To get rid of this, I plugged the *Matte* output of the *Cryptomatte* node into a *Dilate/Erode* node set to *Distance* -1 and used the result in a *Set Alpha* node. This fixed it, but the values might depend on your image.

[image: dilate the mask]

Now perhaps your chain consists of many separate elements instead of being a single object or you might have other objects in the scene. You could of course pick many objects to be visible, but if there are a lot to be kept and just one or a few to be chosen as holdout, it might be easier to pick the ones that should disappear.

In the following example I added a third sphere. To make it easier instead of picking to objects taht should be visible I decide to pick the one that should disappear, the red sphere.

[image: red sphere]

The *Matte* output of the *Cryptomatte* node can now of course be inverted to make the red sphere disappear and the two spheres show up. But here comes the important thing - since the *Cryptomatte* node is applying the matte internally, the *Image* output of it will always hide the two other spheres.

So opposite to what you did before where you could simply pick one sphere and the *Cryptomatte* put out the desired result, you now have to use the original *Image* from the *Render Layer* and plug this into a *Set Alpha* node, where you use the inverted *Matte* output as *Alpha*. As before, you might need a *Dilate/Erode* node to get rid of remaining edges from the hidden object.

[image: inverted matte]

Comment: Oh my goodness, this is such a helpful and thorough answer! Thank you!

Comment: @Aubrie You're welcome. You might consider accepting the answer then.